# Install WTP on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web, plugins, jetty, eclipse-wtp

I'm trying to create a new `dynamic web project` with eclipse, which is not an option under `File -> new ->`

It looks like if I [install Jetty](https://loiane.com/2012/06/jetty-and-eclipse-integration-in-3-steps/), or WTP I'll be able to do that, but there is no dropdown selection for `Eclipse -> Install new Software menu.`, which the instructions in the previous link say I should go to.

When I search `install` in the `help` search bar, the only option that comes up is `Navigate -> Open Setup -> Installation`, and when I click this eclipse just opens the file installation.setup. At this point I don't know what more I can do with this file. [image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185459/how-to-install-jetty-with-eclipse-on-mac) posted some type of an answer to installing jetty, but I don't really know what they're talking about or how to find out if I have the things they are talking about and [other solutions](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/MDW/Installing+Eclipse+Plugins+from+Local) post drop down instructions(e.g. Help -> Install New Software..) that don't actually seem to exist.

I'm using `Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)` of eclipse for MacOS

Comment: It is in the _Help_ menu: _Help > Install New Software..._ (instead of _Navigate > Open Setup > Installation_). Or hit Ctrl+3 and type `Install New Software`.

Comment: @howlger When I search install in the help menu, the only option available to me is `Navigate -> Open Setup -> Installation`. The is nothing that says `Install New Software` when I enter the word `install` into the help menu.

Comment: Do you mean by _help menu_ Quick Access (Ctrl+3)? You have to enter `Install New Software` instead of only `install`. There is also a (text) menu _Help_ containing the subitem _Install New Software..._.

Comment: @howlger Neither works. If I type `install new software` or `install` there is not an option like you're explaining

Comment: Please show a screenshot that shows your whole screen with the main menu bar and the opened _Help_ menu.

Comment: @howlger Ok, added them, the `4 installation.setup` and `Back -> Installation.setup` are just my history

Comment: Please just open the menu without any searching.

Comment: @howlger Thanks! That worked. I don't know which site to enter in though, https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html is the link for the plugin I"m trying to install

Comment: @howlger I might have figured it out, I posted a screen shot of what I'm getting now

Comment: Work with `http://xzer.github.io/run-jetty-run-updatesite/nightly/` to install the [Run-Jetty-Run](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/run-jetty-run) plug-in (the linked instructions refers to an outdated update site at googlecode.com which no longer exists).

Comment: @howlger Thanks! How did you find that? Just a google search? How did you know the other one was missing?

Comment: @howlger I got it installed, theres still no option to create a dynamic web project though.

Comment: Most plug-ins are listed at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/ To create a dynamic web project you need the _Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools_ which can be installed from the Oxygen update site. By the way, Oxygen is two releases behind. To be always uptodate use `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest/`.

Comment: @howlger I saw that link, I didn't understand it because it just told me I was close and to enter the site location in, but didn't tell me what the site location was

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the newest version of Eclipse(currently photon: 2018-09 (4.9.0))

Possibly install the newest JDK and [set it as the default under Eclipse -> Java -> Installed JREs](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-assign_default_jre.htm)

Help -> Install New Software (Do not search anything in the help bar)

Enter `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.12.0/S-3.12.0.M2-20181101035339/repository/`, [as described here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536379) into the works with search bar and click add. Proceed by clicking ok, next, next .....